# Size classes wCompact | hAny and wCompact | hRegular not acting as expected

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard, size-classes

Anyone who has created a new iOS 8.1 project and used Xcode 6.1's storyboard, will have noticed the new size classes. However, I'm getting very strange behavior, and I'm wondering if Apple just messed up, or if I'm misunderstanding something.

When I set constraints in the size class `wCompact | hAny`, they are not applied to all iPhone devices in portrait. However, when I set constraints in the size class `wCompact | hRegular`, they **are** applied to all iPhone devices in portrait.

This is not like the behavior of the size classes `wAny | hCompact` and `wRegular | hCompact`. When I set constraints in the size class `wAny | hCompact`, they are applied to all iPhone devices in landscape, and when I set constraints in the size class `wRegular | hCompact`, they are applied to 5.5 inch iPhone devices in landscape. This behavior makes sense to me: `wAny` should apply to all iPhones in landscape orientation. However, I would then expect `hAny` to apply to all iPhones in portrait orientation, but it does not (as I mentioned above).

It's like Apple accidentally reversed the logic when it comes to portrait orientation. Is this really an accident or am I misunderstanding something?

Thanks!

Comment: This is exactly my question. But looking at the difference between `wRegular` and `hAny` for compact size classes, I do not really know what the _difference_ could be.